# Copy and paste monthly to chaging cell in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

This is an extremely simple question but I am not vary familiar with coding or with google drive scripts and I have been unable to figure much out from other posts.

I am trying to set up a scrip to copy information from cell "C2" to A different cell in column D each month.  (The sheet is tracking monthly expenditures and I want to be able to modify by breakdowns on other sheets and have a record of past levels on this one.  EAch month I want the cell "C2" is copied to to increase (So month 1 it copies to D8 month 2 it copies to D9 ext)

Answer (score 0):

Using a time-driven trigger you might try a function like:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.appendRow(["", "", "", sheet.getRange("C2").getValue()]);
}
```

This presumes data in column-D extends to the last row of data in the sheet and no data is required in columns A-C in the last row of the sheet.

Set the time-driven trigger via Resources -> Current project's triggers